# New Project! New ROS? Which ROS should I use?

Tags: ros2, ros-melodic, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am beginning a new robotics project this Year.

This is my last year in the Univesity and to complete this journey I must build a “Rhex Robot”. And was chosen the ROS, because we already have experience using ROS so it is the best option. However, Which ROS is recommended for this kind of project?

Kinetic ( We used to use this one. ).

Melodic.

Or go ahead into ROS2 ( It is good for “beginners” [ NO PRO YET ] already? )

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341636/new-project!-new-ros?-which-ros-should-i-use?/) by [Teo Cardoso](https://answers.ros.org/users/31965/teo-cardoso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 378 on 2020-01-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2020-01-13**:
What functionality do you need? Navigation? Low-level servo drivers? Camera? Lidar?

I would start by writing a list of the functionality you need then googling to see if it is available in ROS2. If everything is, I would use ROS2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Go with what you know if its for a class project. No reason to add additional burdens to yourself. Kinetic and Melodic are functionally the same so I'd just go with which ever has the least friction (if you are forced to use 16.04 or 18.04). I wouldn't recommend ROS2 for a discrete university project unless the following are true:

- You have spare time
- You *want* to learn ROS2

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2